# Как сделать редирект на страницу пользователя после успешного сохранения новой записи в блоге в Django

Tags: python, django

В моем проекте в Джанго есть форма создания новых постов в блоге:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('text', 'group')
        group = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Post.objects.all(),
                                       required=False, to_field_name="group")
        widgets = {
            'text': forms.Textarea(),
        }

        labels = {
            "group": "Группа",
            "text": "Текст"
        }
```

Также есть вью-функция:

```
# Страница для создания новой записи
def post_create(request):
    groups = Group.objects.all()
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None, files=request.FILES or None)
    context = {
        'groups': groups,
        'form': form,
    }
    if form.is_valid():
        form.instance.author = request.user
        form.save()
        return redirect**('здесь должен быть адрес на редирект')**
    return render(request, 'posts/create_post.html', context)
```

Ну и path из файлика urls.py с адресом страницы нового поста:

```
path('create/', views.post_create, name='post_create')
```

По заданию, после успешного создания нового поста должен быть редирект на страницу профайла залогиненного пользователя.

И вот не могу я понять, как именно прописать такой редирект? Какой параметр передать в строку  return redirect, чтобы подхватилось имя пользователя?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зависит от того, какой ендпоинты в вашем urls.py вернет на страницу автора.

urls.py

```
app_name = "posts"

urlpatterns = [
     path("<str:username>/", views.profile, name="profile"),
]
```

views.py

```
redirect('posts:profile', request.user.username)
```

Примерно так.

Eсли у вас использовано app_name в url.py

иначе `redirect('profile', request.user.username)`

Comment: Спасибо, все заработало!